# How to maintain image quality when it is made to fit into a container without cropping top or bottom

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, background-size

all.
I am trying to set an image as the background inside a div container which will always have the dimensions of the screen of the device. For this purpose, I am providing the css as follows

```css
.outer {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(demo_top.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='outer'>
  </div>
</body>
```

The positive of this code:
-Image quality is maintained.
The negatives of this code:
-Background image is not responsive as the focus is only on centre
-The top and the bottom part of the images are cropped because the position is used as the centre.

What I am looking for is my div to display the entire image without any cropping or image stretching or distortion.
The image size I am using is 2000x2000

Comment: Well, you will want to use a svg image, they work well with responsiveness.

Comment: Isn't there any other way around this? I am hoping to avoid svg because I don't how to develop one. Trying to mend ways with HTML and CSS only

Answer (score 2):

If you want the image to have the same dimensions as your container, you have to use the same image proportions. In this case, the container must also be square (1x1). If the proportions of both elements are not equal, the only solution is to stretch one side of the image or to cut it.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but no change after adding object-fit

Comment: If i give the same dimensions to the background image as I have given to the outer div, then there is no cropping of the image from top or bottom but the entire image looks stretched or distored

Answer (score 0):

Instead of background-size: cover, you need to use contain. This will allow the image to be as large as possible without cropping outside the div and with no stretching/distoring.

```
-webkit-background-size:contain;
-moz-background-size:contain;
-o-background-size:contain;
background-size:contain;
```

Comment: background-size: contain doesn't capture the entire div. The idea is to capture the entire div